# C - data cannot be assigned to global variable

Tags: c

I have an external variable `char myArr[3]` and I am trying to assign something to it. For example, inside my function, I have, `myArr[3] = {1,2,3}`. The compiler tells me that I have "unexpected token: =", but as soon as I declare my variable locally, (`myArr[3] = {1,2,3}`), the error disappears. I tried masking the external variable inside my function with no results.

```
char myArr[3];

void my func(){
    myArr = {1,2,3}
}
```

Comment: you are trying to set a character to an array.

Comment: Please post the real code. (are you missing semicolons?)

Comment: @Dmitry its just a char array. As soon as I do it locally, the error disappears

Comment: Please post a complete example that illustrates what you are doing. In particular where do you have `myArr[3] = {1,2,3}` in each case?

Comment: How do you import the external?

Comment: Is it an initializer or an assignment?

Comment: @perreal, its just a global variable defined outside of my functions

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski `myArr` is a char array, but `myArr[3]` is a *single* character (*not* an array).

Comment: This is not a discussion place, this is a place for clear questions and answers. Explain your intent, and what you did, rather than just posting what you did and telling us "why doesnt this work?"

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski The longer you take to follow instructions, the longer it will take for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: myarr[] is an array. and an array is not an lvalue. ( := you cannot assign to it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
char myArr[3] = { 1, 2, 3}
```

You are creating an array of 3 characters, and setting them to the values 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

When you do

```
myArr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

you are trying to set `myArr[3]` (which is the *fourth* character in an array of three characters by the way; you are going "out of bounds") to `{ 1, 2, 3 }` which doesn't make sense. In C you cannot set arrays like that: it's a syntax error.

If you want to set your array to the values 1, 2 and 3 try this:

```
myArr[0] = 1;
myArr[1] = 2;
myArr[2] = 3;
```

Comment: Ahah! I dont know what I was thinking. Long day man.. long day!

Comment: declaring a local variable and at the end of my function, making my global = my local. For example, if i did char myLocalArr[3] inside my function and then myArr = myLocalArr. I would still get an error

Comment: An array is not an "l-value" - you cannot assign to it.